# How to fix a web3.py HTTPConnectionPool read timeout error

Tags: web3.py, python, web3-providers

I have a `web3.py` program running and everything was seemingly working. I was connecting to my local server via the automatic connection offered in `web3.py`.

I am now getting the following error:

`requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8545): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)`

This *only* happens when I am trying to send a transaction. I can read the nonce from the server, but when I attempt to send a transaction with `web3.py`, I get this timeout.

I have seen [this](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/145#issuecomment-437100574) comment 20 days ago which offers a potential solution. My problem here is that I do not know if it is possible to change the `HTTPProvider` timeout when automatically connecting. Is this a solution? If so, how can you change the timeout when auto-connecting to the node?